# How do i retrieve details of currently logged in user from AspNetUsers table in Blazor Server app Using Identity Framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have built a blazor server app which uses user authentication. During Registration it  asks users to enter Their Personnel Number which is stored in AspNetUser table. I want to display this Pno when user successfully logs in but I can't seem to do it. I have tried many different approaches suggested by different sites and none of them seems to work.

For the reference this is what my table looks like.

[image: Table]

I tried to use AuthenticationStateProvider package but it isn't working either.

Comment: Please show us some code. How `IdentityBuilder` is configured? How did you try to use `AuthenticationStateProvider`? What is exactly "not working"?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already put the phone number in the database, you can try the following code to display it on your web page:

```
@UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(@User.Identity?.Name).Result.PhoneNumber;
```

Note:
Using ***FindByEmailAsync*** is because the email here is the default name of the account.

Comment: Why would i want to display phone number? I specifically said i want to display Pno.

Comment: Just change it as Result.Pno